# Starting multiple Screen windows from shell script uses wrong configuration

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, gnu-screen, stty

When running Screen, I can use <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to create a new window and run vim in each window. Also from Screen, I can run the command `screen vim` multiple times to open new windows with vim already running. These work as expected. However...

If I put the command multiple times in a script, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen vim
screen vim
screen vim
```

...and run that script from within Screen, the first command will run as expected, but the second and following ones will not.

Things I have noticed are:

1. Window 2 and beyond does not have `stty -ixon` applied, which I have set in .bashrc
2. If I don't have `colorscheme` set explicitly in .vimrc, it will use one scheme in window 1 and another in all following windows
3. Sometimes a command will be skipped, i.e., sometimes only two new windows will be opened where the script was set to open three
4. If I do a `:windowlist`, window 2 and following will not have the login flag set (running `screen vim` directly will set this flag), e.g.,

```
Num Name Flags
  0 bash     $
  1 vim      $  <-- running the script from window 0 opened 1..3 (no flag on 2 or 3)
  2 vim
  3 vim
  4 vim      $  <-- manually running `screen vim` from window 0 always sets the flag
```

5. Using <kbd>Ctrl+a</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> on a window that's not logged in will return the message `This window is not logged in` and the flag will not be set. Pressing the keys again will then toggle between logged in and out (though `stty -ixon` etc' will still not be applied)
6. Running `htop` will show all instances of vim (including ones that are not logged in) are running under my user.

Why does manually opening multiple windows apply my settings correctly, but using a script doesn't?

I am new to Linux and not sure if I'm doing something silly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found that the problem is caused by the script running all commands (except the first) in the background. I can force the first command to have the same problem by forking it with `&`.

After not being able to find a way to have the script run each command in the foreground, one-after-the-other, I have found an alternative solution...

I can put all the commands in a custom screenrc file (e.g., my_screenrc) as such:

```
# Import default screenrc
source ${HOME}/.screenrc

# Run screen-specific commands (not bash ones)
screen     # Run bash in window 0
screen vim # Run vim in windows 1 through 3 (with correct settings)
screen vim
screen vim
```

I can then run this from bash with:

```
screen -c my_screenrc
```